# unmarshall without XmlRoot

Tags: java, jaxb

After reading the below blog I marshalled an object.
[missing XMLRoot](http://lifentek.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/unable-to-marshall-due-to-missing-xmlrootelement-annotation/)

```
T objectToSerialize;
JAXBElement<T> je=new JAXBElement<T>(new QName(“namespace”,”RootName”), T.class,objectToSerialize );
marshaller.marshall(je,writer);
```

Now I want to unmarshall it and since the class that i marshalled has no XmlRoot annotation. How can i unmarshal this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use one of the unmarshal methods that takes a `Class` parameter.

```
JAXBElement<Foo> je = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Foo.class);
Foo foo = je.getValue();
```